# referencing new objects with super/subclass references JAVA

Tags: java, inheritance, reference, subclass, superclass

Im currently learning java and couldn't understand this topic. 
referencing sub class objects with super class. After going through multiple websites and posts, my confusion has just increased. 
Example code:

```
 public abstract class Bird {
    private void fly() {
        System.out.println("Bird is flying");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bird bird = new Pelican();
        bird.fly();
    }
}
class Pelican extends Bird {
    protected void fly() {
        System.out.println("Pelican is flying");
    }
}
```

The output is Bird is flying - why?

Also I have 3 questions:

```
Bird bird = new Pelican();
```

1. In the above part, what can I use in place of Bird type (if there are more classes extending Bird)? I'm preparing for the OCA 1 exam and the questions on this topic are confusing me a lot.
2. What methods and variables are output when using these references? In the above example, pelican object is created but fly method that runs is bird?
3. If Casting is done, what types I can use and what types I cant?

There are multiple questions about this on stackoverflow and other java websites but multiple sources,multiple answers are confusing to me. I understand time is valuable but can someone please clear this doubt once and for all for me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for you to call the method from subclass you have to use method overriding which is also known as runtime polymorphism. As the object that you have declared is Bird and it has a private method of fly which cant be overriden, your output will be "Bird is flying".

However if you were to initialize it as

Pelican pelican = new Pelican();

then the output would be "Pelican is flying"

You can read more about it here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-method-dispatch-runtime-polymorphism-java/

Comment: So, if the code is modified to have a public method fly for both classes,  then the overridden method will execute? - Will try on a computer when I get home but just wanted to know if there are any other factors in deciding which method will run.

Comment: yes, do remember to add @Override annotation on Pelican’s fly() method

Answer (score 0):

In ur Bird abstract class the method fly is private. You cannot inherit or override a private method: hence

```
class Pelican extends Bird {
 protected void fly() { System.out.println("Pelican is flying"); }
 }
```

is not actually overriding the parent method.

Moreover, your code has **compilation issues** since you cannot call a private method of reference class and in your Bird Class, the **method fly is Private**.

Compile the code again.

Comment: I have directly copy pasted the question from OCA 1 book by Sybex without any modifications. It says the answer is "Bird is flying". So the question might be wrong?

Comment: @Chandradhar yes I am afraid so, you can just paste the code in any IDE or Java compiler and see the results by urself.

Comment: @Chandradhar if the answer helps you, would you please upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Welcome to Polymorphism in Java!

First of all, you **cannot create an instance of an abstract class** which is the causes of compilation issue here.

The Output is not "*Pelican is flying*" because private method cannot be overridden, as you are creating pelican object (Child class) with Bird reference (Parent class).

```
Bird bird = new Pelican();
```

If you want the desired Output "*Pelican is flying*" you need the reference of Child class as well.

```
Pelican bird = new Pelican();
```

Comment: @Hades so did I specify in my answer